# Zend Core Administrator Problem

Tags: php, zend-server

I am quite new to PHP Environment and I've started learning it so I've installed ZendCore. I was trying to change root directory to separate the root from ProgramFiles like `inetpub` so I change PHP Server Root and `localhost:81/` still works but not run the under the folder I created, instead it points at the same old default folder but the problem is ZendCore is not working and it says `No input file specified.` when I type in `localhost:81/ZendCore/`

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ... first of all I'd stop using Zend Core and Start using Zend Server or Zend Server CE unless there is a compelling reason to use Core.  Core is Zend's older product and has been replaced by Zend Server.

Comment: Well actually it is not quite an answer but you are the only one who answered my question and I am gonna mark your answer as an answer.